# CanJS - Two way binding

Tags: canjs, canjs-routing, canjs-view

How to do two-way binding using CanJS?

```
Enter the Text : <input type="text" name="name" can-value="enteredText" />
Display the Text: {{enteredText}}
```

Can show multiple approaches? Using ViewModel ?

Answer (score 1):

`can-value` was the old method in v2. In Canjs 4.0, you would do two way binding like this:

```
Enter the Text : <input type="text" name="name" value:bind="enteredText" />
Display the Text: {{enteredText}}
```

See: https://canjs.com/doc/can-stache-bindings.twoWay.html

Here's a jsbin demonstrating the syntax:

http://jsbin.com/vogavevico/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here (docu [for v2](https://v2.canjs.com/docs/can.view.bindings.twoWay.html) and [for v3](http://canjs.com/doc/can-stache-bindings.html)).

At least if you use the (nowadays recommended) components approach you can write

```
<my-component {(some-prop)}="value"/><!-- v2 -->
<!-- syntax for v3 remains: {(prop)}="key" for two-way binding. -->
```

This is from the documentation.